# Error length(url) == 1 is not TRUE when web scraping

Tags: r, web-scraping, rselenium

I have got the following link:
https://www.senamhi.gob.pe/mapas/mapa-estaciones-2/_dato_esta_tipo02.php?estaciones=109045&CBOFiltro=202112&t_e=M&estado=DIFERIDO&cod_old=154107&cate_esta=PLU&alt=2266
I want to do web scrapping by using R. The objective is to replace in this part "202112" the last to digits with "01", "02", "03" and so on until 12 and then download the information for each page by pressing automatically the buttom. I have the following code, but get this error.

```
library(RSelenium)

download_senamhi_data <- function(url_list) {
  
  # NUMERO ALEATORIO DE PUERTO 
  port <- as.integer(runif(1, min = 5000, max = 6000))
  
  # EJECUTAMOS EL DRIVER DE GOOGLE CHROME 
  rD <- rsDriver(port = port, browser = "chrome", 
                 chromever = "101.0.4951.15")
  
  remDrv <- rD$client
  
  for (url in url_list){
  
  # INGRESAR AL URL
  remDrv$navigate(url)
  
  # ENCONTRAR EL BOTON DE DESCARGA 
  down_button <- remDrv$findElement(using = "id", "export2")
  down_button$clickElement()
  
  }
  
  # CERRAR LA SESION ACTUAL
  remDrv$close()
  rD$server$stop()
  rm(rD, remDrv)
  gc()

}

# EJECUTAR LA FUNCION PARA DESCARGAR TODOS LOS MESES DE UN AÑO

list_url <- list()

for (i in 1:9) {
  
  list_url[i] = paste("https://www.senamhi.gob.pe/mapas/mapa-estaciones-2/_dato_esta_tipo02.php?estaciones=109045&CBOFiltro=20210",
               i, "&t_e=M&estado=DIFERIDO&cod_old=154107&cate_esta=PLU&alt=2266", sep = "")
  
 }

for (i in 10:12) {
  
  list_url[i] = paste("https://www.senamhi.gob.pe/mapas/mapa-estaciones-2/_dato_esta_tipo02.php?estaciones=109045&CBOFiltro=2021",
               i, "&t_e=M&estado=DIFERIDO&cod_old=154107&cate_esta=PLU&alt=2266", sep = "")
  
}

download_senamhi_data(list_url)

Error in checkError(res) : 
Undefined error in httr call. httr output: length(url) == 1 is not TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

If `{Rselenium}` isn't a strict requirement here, we could extract those tables from a list of urls with `{rvest}`. Site's CSV export is not considerably better, it converts HTML table to CSV with client-side JavaScript.

Here I'm using `purrr::map`for iterating through lists instead of a for-loop:

```r
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

# build a vector of 12 urls
urls <- paste0("https://www.senamhi.gob.pe/mapas/mapa-estaciones-2/_dato_esta_tipo02.php",
               "?estaciones=109045&CBOFiltro=2021", sprintf("%.2d", 1:12),
               "&t_e=M&estado=DIFERIDO&cod_old=154107&cate_esta=PLU&alt=2266")

# read content of all urls,
# from each page extract dataTable,
# parse table content,
# bind list of tibbles (1 per each month) into one,
# filter out header rows (first column is not a date string),
# set column names,
# convert date strings to dates and measuremnts to numeric

df <- urls %>% 
  map(read_html, .progress = TRUE) %>% 
  map(html_element, "table#dataTable") %>% 
  map(html_table) %>% 
  bind_rows() %>% 
  filter(grepl("^\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}$",X1)) %>% 
  set_names(c("date", "temp_max", "temp_min", "hum_rel", "prec")) %>% 
  mutate(date = lubridate::ymd(date)) %>% 
  mutate(across(temp_max:prec, as.numeric))

# save as csv:
readr::write_csv(df, "out.csv")
```

Resulting 365 row dataset for a whole year:

```r
df
#> # A tibble: 365 × 5
#>    date       temp_max temp_min hum_rel  prec
#>    <date>        <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 2021-01-01       NA       NA      NA   0  
#>  2 2021-01-02       NA       NA      NA   1.2
#>  3 2021-01-03       NA       NA      NA   1.9
#>  4 2021-01-04       NA       NA      NA   0  
#>  5 2021-01-05       NA       NA      NA   6  
#>  6 2021-01-06       NA       NA      NA   1.9
#>  7 2021-01-07       NA       NA      NA   4.2
#>  8 2021-01-08       NA       NA      NA   2.5
#>  9 2021-01-09       NA       NA      NA   0  
#> 10 2021-01-10       NA       NA      NA   0  
#> # ℹ 355 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you. It helped me a lot